# How to add an object from another scene?

Tags: append

I'm am trying to create a scene in Blender, by adding in another object from a previously created scene that is on a separate .blend file. How can I do this?
I have tried to append an object from one .blend to another, but it still won't work. Can I get some help in trying to figure this out?

The other answers to this question haven't worked. Is it a bug? How can I do this?

Comment: I don't mean to close this question, but there is a lot of duplicate information available in the link above.

Comment: Are both scenes in the same blend file? Please try give more info in your questions.

Comment: The way this question is currently phrased, it *is* an exact duplicate of one already asked. If you meant something else and want to clarify your question, please do so and it will be reopened.

Comment: It is in different scenes. Sorry, I didn't know it was a duplicate. I am new here so i don't know how to find questions already asked specific to my need.

Comment: O.k. I tried to APPEND from the file menu and I selected my .blend file that I wanted to pull from and it still won't come up.

Comment: That link does not answer my question.

Comment: @OwenPatterson did you try the answer below?

Comment: No because it is not in the same .blend file.

Comment: To add an object from another scene is quite different from adding an object from another file. It is really annoying that this is marked as duplicate.

Comment: One answer that is not in the other topic is: drag the object in the outliner an drop it **in the outliner** to another scene. This puts kind of a reference to the other scene and if the original object is changed, the changes apply also to the other scene. That's by the way what I was looking for and was prevented from due to this obsessive "this is a duplicate" habit.

Answer (score 20):

If the scenes are in the same .blend file:

1. Be in the destination scene
2. From the Outliner, make sure you see all scenes
3. In the Outliner, expand the scene with the object you want and drill down to that object
4. Left-click and drag the **icon** for that object into your 3D View
5. Boom... you've copied it over

If the scenes are in different files

1. File > Append (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)
2. From Blender's File Browser, go to the .blend file you want to pull from
3. Left-click the .blend file and go to the Object sub-directory within it
4. Choose the object you want to get (you did give it a sensible name, right?)
5. Click the "Link/Append from Library" button in the upper right corner

Comment: Great. You made my day!

Comment: The objects are in the same file / different scenes for me, but the child objects of the parent dragged into the scene do not appear in the target scene, what did I do wrong?

Comment: There's a chance that the drag and drop method doesn't include child objects. For that, you may want to work from the 3D View. Change to the source scene, select all of the objects you want to bring to the target scene, and use Ctrl+L > Objects to Scene and choose your target scene. Then go back to the target scene and use L > All to make your linked objects local to that scene.