# Using groups in other files

Tags: modeling, groups, blend-files

I've modeled a clock and saved it as clock using blender 2.56. I've also modeled a room using blender 2.56 and saved it as room. I've made the clock a group and named this group clock. How do I open up my room file and then open up the clock group in the room
file or scene?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to *File* > *Append* or press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> , you can navigate to the blend file, open the *Group* folder and import the group.

[image]

Appending the group will create a unique copy of it in the new file. If you want to keep working on the group in the original file and have any changes there be updated in the new file, you should *Link* instead. Go to *File > Link* or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>. Note that if you link however, you won't be able to edit the linked group.

Related - [How to add an object from another scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1444/12).