# Is there a way to export the color palette (paint mode)?

Tags: export, import, texture-painting

I often use the painting tool of Blender,while painting, based on the color I use, blender creates a palette of the color I mostly used.

Now, I would like to export this palette to  be sure to use the same color scheme for another 3D model I'm doing.

In others words, I want to export this one and then import this palette for my new project.

Here is the palette I'm talking about. 
Do you know how to do that? I haven't found a way to accomplish this at the moment.

[image: The color palette I need to export]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Import palette from another blend

When you'd like to save a palette using standard features press *New* button in the palettes dropdown list. New palette will be saved and used instead of default one:

[image]

When some changes are made so it to contain desired hues, save the file and open new one. Select option to [link or append from file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-to-add-an-object-from-another-scene), navigate to that saved file and search for Palettes folder:

[image]

You will see there as many palettes as you created in original file.

#### Paint Palette addon

It's possible to use Paint Palette addon for that, which is bundled with Blender. Addon will save your palette in .gpl format, so you should be able to share saved palette in GIMP (or import that in Blender using this addon):

[image]

1. Press "+" button located leftwards to add a color to palette.
2. Press "Browse" button to *select* folder where you'd like to save and click  "Accept" there.
3. Press "+" button in the top right to save preset using selected path.

Comment: NB, in case anyone else is going mad trying to import a saved gpl file into blender IT SEEMS TO BE CRUCIAL to uncheck the 'Relative Path' option (defaults true) after clicking the 'Browse path 2' button in the above diagram.