# How to export/import color palette from Brush in Texture Paint tab - Blender 2.8 Beta

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

How can I export/import a color palette from Brush tool in Texture Paint tab for Blender 2.8 Beta?

I would like to use this palette in another project.

I found a previous question for an older version, but I am unable to find the same options: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41136/65827

My Brush options looks like the following image, there doesn't appear to be a way of exporting/importing palette:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save your palette in a blend file, you can append that palette into a new file to work with. name it something so you can differentiate it from generic names if you want to keep from losing track, but the steps are pretty straight forward.
File>Append, then navigate to the source blend file, and once appended, choose it from the palette drop down menu.
[image][image][image][image]

Comment: It works, much appreciated!